# ¿Cómo actualizar estado de una reserva pasada las 1 hora de haberla hecho? PHP

Tags: php, mysql, time

[image: Estado de las Reservas]

Tengo un sistema de reservas que cuando el cliente reserva sin pagar, tiene 1 hora ir hacia el local para pagar y confirmar la reserva, en todo caso si pasa las 1 hora quiero que esa reserva vuelva automáticamente a estar en verde, o sea disponible. Aluna sugerencia? Gracias

Comment: pon el código que usas

Answer (score 0):

Puedes usar la funcion de Wordpress `wp_schedule_event` te dejo la referencia a la documentación de la función:
https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_schedule_event/